# Eclipse - Import project grayed out

Tags: java, eclipse

I am completely new to Java and Eclipse. I am unable to import a project into Eclipse as it is grayed out. Spent some time searching on google but got nothing useful. Would like some help.

Below is the file structure and the issue

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message says "they already exist in the workspace" ...

Comment: @DavidPostill how can i remove it from the workspace so I can add it again ?

Comment: Please read the Eclipse help. [Deleting projects](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-42b.htm)

Comment: And [Where in an Eclipse workspace is the list of projects stored? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251116/where-in-an-eclipse-workspace-is-the-list-of-projects-stored)